# Remove OK button from kartik-v custom dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, kartik-v

I tried to create a custom dialog using `yii2-dialog`, one of the `kartik-v` widgets. I want to create this dialog with a single button: `Statistics` so, using the documentation provided in the demo, I wrote the code below.

The problem is that the dialog I get has two buttons instead of one and I CAN NOT get rid of the OK button.

My questions are: is there any way to create a custom dialog using yii2-dialog with a single button? and if possible, how can I achieve this?

```
use kartik\dialog\Dialog;
use yii\web\JsExpression;

echo Dialog::widget([
    'libName' => 'krajeeDialogCust',
    'overrideYiiConfirm' => false,
    'options' => [
        'size' => Dialog::SIZE_LARGE,
        'type' => Dialog::TYPE_SUCCESS,
        'title' => 'My Dialog',
        'message' => 'This is an entirely customized bootstrap dialog from scratch.',
        'buttons' => [
            [
                'id' => 'cust-btn-1',
                'label' => 'Statistics',
                'action' => new JsExpression("function(dialog) {
                    dialog.setTitle('Title 1');
                    dialog.setMessage('This is a custom message for button number 1');
                }")
            ],
        ]
    ]
]);

// button for testing the custom krajee dialog box
echo '<button type="button" id="btn-custom" class="btn btn-success">Custom Dialog</button>';

// javascript for triggering the dialogs
$js = <<< JS
$("#btn-custom").on("click", function() {
    krajeeDialogCust.dialog(
        "Welcome to a customized Krajee Dialog! Click the close icon on the top right to exit.",
        function(result) {
            // do something
        }
    );
});
JS;

// register your javascript
$this->registerJs($js);
```

And this is what I'm getting:

[image: I want to get rid of the OK blue button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`dialogDefaults`**](http://demos.krajee.com/dialog#option-dialogDefaults) option, according to the docs the configuration options to be setup as defaults for the bootstrap dialog (applicable when `useNative` is `false`). and the default value for `useNative` is `false` until you explicitly set to `true`.

Update your `Dialog` definition to below and override the `buttons` property in the `dialogDefault` option as the plugin sets the `ok` and `cancel` buttons by default.

```
echo Dialog::widget ( [
    'libName' => 'krajeeDialogCust' ,
    'overrideYiiConfirm' => false ,
    'dialogDefaults' => [
        Dialog::DIALOG_OTHER => [
            'buttons' => ''
        ]
    ] ,
```